# Generating PDF with Charts in Laravel 5

Tags: charts, laravel-5, dompdf

I'm working on Laravel 5 and I have a view where I displayed some graphs of Charts, the thing is that I want to offer to the user, the posibility of download this report in PDF, I'm currently generating reports with DomPDF, but as I was reading, DomPDF doesn't support this kind of graph, so, How can I do it? I was thinking in generate a printing view, but then how I dowload it automatically?
Also, I was thinking to send the generated images through a post petition and then attach it to the generated PDF, can I do that?

Comment: What chart solution are you using? It might help to see a sample of the code you're using to generate your report, or to have more of a description of your solution.

Comment: If you can generate images of the charts you should be able to pass those back to the server and either save to the server file system for referencing from your HTML or for encoding in base64 to embed in the HTML via  data-uri.